# Labels become textboxes on click edit of specific row

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, gridview, razor

I am trying to develop a full functional Gridview in MVC, data is showing in gridview but I want to edit one row on the same page ie the row should become textboxes when I click edit hyperlink.

here is my html code

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.Label("ID") 
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.Label("Name")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.Label("Description")
        </th>
        <th>
             @Html.Label("Date")
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text"  class="edit-input" />
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="edit-input" />
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="edit-input" />
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="edit-input" />
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_date)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a class="edit" href="#">Edit</a> |
           @* @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |*@
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

my jQuery

```
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.edit').click(function () {
            var dad = $(this).parent().parent();
            dad.find('label').hide();
            dad.find('input[type="text"]').show().focus();
        });

        $('input[type=text]').focusout(function() {
            var dad = $(this).parent();
            $(this).hide();
            dad.find('label').show();
        });
        });
    </script>
}
```

and my css for textboxes

```
.edit-input {
    display:none;
}
```

but when I execute the screen i like this[image]

I am new to mvc and I don't have much knowledge about it, 
what should I change in jQuery to fix it?

Comment: http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo-bs3.html

Comment: Can you use HTML5? contenteditable=true on the <td> elements would make this work.

Comment: contenteditable="true" didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the html generated by `@Html.DisplayFor()`. Unless you have created a custom `DiplayTemplate` it wont wrap the display text in a `<label>` tag which is what you script is trying to hide  by using `dad.find('label').hide();`.

Instead, wrap the display text in a container

```
<td>
  <input type="text"  class="edit-input" />
  <div class="displaytext">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Id)
  </div>
</td>
```

and adjust you script to

```
....
$('a.edit').click(function () {
  var dad = $(this).parent().parent();
  dad.find('.displaytext').hide(); // change this
  dad.find('input[type="text"]').show().first().focus();
});

$('input[type=text]').focusout(function() {
  var dad = $(this).parent();
  $(this).hide();
  dad.find('.displaytext').show(); // and this
});
```

Note you will probably also want to copy the contents of the display text to the input when you make it visible.

Comment: it just let me edit the date, other columns in a row don't change into textboxes

Comment: Sorry, don't understand. Are the 'labels` now hiding?

Comment: yes I changed <input type="text"  class="edit-input" /> to  @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Id, new { style = "display: none;" })

Comment: Using `<input type="text" class="edit-input" />` or `@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Id, new { style="display: none;" })` is irrelevant (and you should not use `style="display: none;"`, but rather use css to initially hide the text boxes textboxes). What do you mean by _it just let me edit the date_?

Comment: Note also you will need to change the second part of the script when you show the display text. `dad.find('.displaytext').show();`

Comment: now when I click on edit of a row just Date column turns into textbox while the whole row should change into textboxes

Comment: Then there is something else wrong in your html or script. What does `dad.find('input[type="text"]').length` return (it should return `4`).

Comment: Note also your use of `.focus()` is going to focus the last textbox. It probably should be `dad.find('input[type="text"]').show().first().focus();`

Comment: thank you so much, I works fine now, but data is not saving when I change in textbox

Comment: What do you mean not saving - you have not shown any code for how you save. You will need to ask a separate question with the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Could you add a hidden text box in each row? And then when you click the row, hide the content of each td, but show the text box?

```
<td>

            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Id)
           @Html.TextBox(modelItem => item.Holiday_Id, new{style="display:none;"})
        </td>

<Script>
   $(function(){
    $(".edit").click(function(){
       $(this).parent().parent().children("td > * :not('label')").hide();
       $(this).children("input").show();
    });

   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has two issues. As mentioned by @Stephen Muecke  `@Html.DisplayFor()` doesn't generate `<label>` tag. And  in `dad.find('input[type="text"]').show().focus();`  method `focus()` runs for each input and set focus to it, but the previous input lost focus and raise it focusout() event (exactly hide it).So that why you can edit only Date, because it last input and don't lose `focus()`. I've simulated your situation according  @Stephen Muecke  modifications and it's works fine. You can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dfx4nxg6/5/)

Comment: OP did actually have `var dad = $(this).parent();` for the `focusout` event :)

Comment: Yes, you're right. Your answer is fully correct. I'll will modify my :)